# How can I move/copy files with a GUI "File Conflict" dialog in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, gtk

I want move/copy files with python and have conflicts (when there are naming conflicts with files in the destination) spawn a GUI dialog that gives the normal options.  Skip, replace, do this for all, etc.  Ideal it would force the file manager to execute the move command, but I can't find a way to do that which is file manager agnostic (or even one that's particular to mine - Nemo).

I want to avoid having to write that myself, and I'm hoping there's a library, or some other to do it.

I'm writing in python or python3 in Linux Mint 20 Cinnamon.  Hoping to support more platforms than that, but let's start there.

Comment: I'm a little confused here. Just to clarify: are you asking if there's a way to force files to be replaced without question, ideally one that you don't have to code, in a file browser that you are writing? Or are you asking how to check if the file already exists before replacing it, and if it does exist, how to ask the user if they want to replace it or not?

Comment: No, I'm asking how to invoke the system file manager for copying files.  Some kind of xdg-system-copy-function, or the like.  And failing that, some python library that copies in that way.

Comment: Ah, that make sense. Thanks for clarifying! I will let you know if I find anything...